# How to send emails with conditional attachments?

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

When you use a userform in VBA to send an email is there an option to conditionally add an attachment?

[image: Example userform]

Let's say

- if checkboxes 1 & 2 are checked, IMG1 will be attached
- if checkbox 3 is checked, IMG2 will be attached
- If checkboxes 1, 2 and 3 are checked, IMG1 and IMG2 will be attached

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim AppOutlook As Outlook.application
    Dim Mailtje As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String
    Set AppOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mailtje = AppOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Mailtje.Display
    Mailtje.To = TextBox1.Value
    Mailtje.CC = TextBox2.Value
    Mailtje.Subject = "Test" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy")
    Mailtje.HTMLBody = strbody
    .Attachments.Add = IMG1.jpg
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried something with the Case statement, but this only got me errors. Somehow the checkboxes would not be read as values and attach a document in the outgoing mail.

"Select Case checkbox1.Value = true

       Case 1
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 1 tej"
       Case 2
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 2 tej"
       Case 3
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 3 tej"
       Case 4
               .Attachments.Add = filePath & "123 4 tej"

 End Select''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```vb
If checkbox1.Value And checkbox2.Value Then
    Mailtje.Attachments.Add "C:\Test\Pic1.jpg" 'use the full path
End If
If checkbox3.Value Then
    Mailtje.Attachments.Add "C:\Test\Pic2.jpg"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Tim :) I am now able to add the picture as an attachment based on the checkboxes! I was tinkering so long to achieve this